# NPE android.content.ContentResolver.insert when trying to create new calendar

Tags: android

Below code works on emulator / Motorola but fails with exception below on Samsung Galaxy Android 7.0. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
            UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "Example1");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, "Example1 calendar");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "Example1 Calendar");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, "39A0FF");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, userCredentials.get_ID());
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "METHOD_ALERT, METHOD_EMAIL, METHOD_ALARM");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_ATTENDEE_TYPES, "TYPE_OPTIONAL, TYPE_REQUIRED, TYPE_RESOURCE");
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_AVAILABILITY, "AVAILABILITY_BUSY, AVAILABILITY_FREE, AVAILABILITY_TENTATIVE");

            Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
            uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
                    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "Example1")
                    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL).build();
            Uri calendarURI = app.getContentResolver().insert(uri, contentValues);
```

I get excetion

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1699)
>                         at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                         at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                         at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
>                         at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1280)

Comment: do you have the right permissions?

Comment: @just Yes... i have right permissions...FYI it works on Motorola device.